# How to get the string that start after the last > by regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am writing a C# code that read a webpage and grep the content from the webpage.
I spent a lot of time to figure the content and now I stuck on this:

```
<i class="icon"></i><a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/12/us/irma-storm-updates.html">Latest Updates: 90 Percent of Houses in Florida Keys Are Damaged
```

I wanna get the "Latest Updates: 90 Percent of Houses in Florida Keys Are Damaged" only
I used to use "(?<=\">)(.*)" to get some content out successfully but not fit for all of it.
Therefore, how could I use R.E. to point I want the element that start get after the last ' > '

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest using an HTML parser.  However if you must use a regex, what language are you using?

Comment: I am using C#, it's a assignment from my working place.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Regex you need here is a working example in RegexStorm.net [example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3E%28%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2B%29&i=%3Ci%20class%3D%22icon%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2017%2F09%2F12%2Fus%2Firma-storm-updates.html%22%3ELatest%20Updates%3A%2090%20Percent%20of%20Houses%20in%20Florida%20Keys%20Are%20Damaged):

```
>([^<>]+)
```

This says:  Find a string that matches a closing angle bracket, followed by text that doesn't include angle brackets.  The [^<>] says find letters, numbers, whitespace that are NOT open/close angle brackets.  The parenthesis around the [^<>] captures the text as a separate group.  The (+) says get at least one or more.

Here is a C# example that uses it.  You need to get the second capture group for the text you want.

```
void Main()
{
    string text = "<i class=\"icon\"></i><a href=\"https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/12/us/irma-storm-updates.html\">Latest Updates: 90 Percent of Houses in Florida Keys Are Damaged";
    Regex regex = new Regex(">([^<>]+)");

    MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(text);

    if (matchCollection != null)
    {
        foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

RegexStorm.net is a good .Net test site.  Regex101.com is a good site to learn different Regex tools.

Comment: I am not a good R.E. user, I feel headache with this-_-"
one question what is the > and + means?
Do you have any good suggestion and resources to learn R.E. ? I learned R.E. in Computer Logic courses when I was in University....I feel I learned nothing now.

Comment: I tried it's realllllllllllllllllly close the only problem is the string a contained > at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Did you get m.Groups[1].Value?  That is the second capture group.  The first capture group will contain the >.

Answer (score 0):

If the substring that you want to match appears after the last `>` then the main thing you know about it is that it *does not* contain a `>`. This is matched with `[^>]`. If the string must contain at least one character then you'll want to use `+` as the quantifier; if it's allowed to be empty then you'll want to use `*` to allow for zero matches. Finally, you need to match the full remainder of the text, up to the end of the line, which you do with a `$`.

So the full expression is `[^>]*$` (or `[^>]+$` if it can't be zero length).

If you want to also require that the preceding text *does* have a `>`, you can make it a bit more complicated, using a non-matching look-behind, `(?<=\>)`. This says to find a `>` (which needs to be escaped here with `\>`) but don't include it in the match. The final expression would then be `(?<=\>)[^>]*$`. Now, C# strings also make use of `\` for escaping, so you have to escape it twice before passing it to the `Regex` constructor. So it becomes `new Regex("(?<=\\>)[^>]*$")`.

The simpler version, `[^>]*$`, is probably sufficient for your needs.

Finally, I would add that parsing XML or HTML with regular expressions is usually the wrong thing to do because there are lots of edge cases, and you will have to make assumptions about the formatting. For example, based on your example text, I assumed you are searching up to the end of the input text. It's usually better to parse XML with an XML parser, which won't have these problems.

Comment: holy ....your expression is worked....
is that possible to combine these two expression in one?
string titleRegex = "(?<=story-heading)(.*)(?=</a)";
string titleRegexFinal = "(?<=>)[^>]*$";

what I did is use the titleRegex to get a string first then trim by the next R.E., it's a little bit like cheating.

Comment: @JackyCheung There are plenty of free resources online. To begin, try looking in the [Stackoverflow Regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) which has plenty of links and resources. Scroll down to the "Further Reading" section, but the text of the page also offers some basics.